# Windows xp Change Wallpaper to Webpage

Tags: windows, registry, wallpaper

To do this manual i just pick a html file in the change wallpaper dialog and tada works..

but if i want to do this from code what api calls / reg keys must i change?

Iv tryed this SystemParametersInfo (WinAPI) didnt work and i have found out that "HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Internet Explorer\Desktop\General\Wallpaper" and "HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Themes\LastTheme\Wallpaper" are changed to the html page.. but just editing those to from code does not change the wallpaper..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to use HTML as wallpaper, ActiveDesktop needs to be enabled first.  Assuming that is already the case, then the [IActiveDesktop interface](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb776357.aspx) has a [SetWallpaper() method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb776362.aspx) available.  Have a look at MSDN's "[Using the Active Desktop Object](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb776830.aspx)" article for how to access IActiveDesktop.